# Gnoplot: Plotting polar density

Tags: electron, gnuplot, probability-density

I have numerical wavefunction in radial (r-coordinate) and have to add spherical harmonics with theta [i.e, psi(r, theta)=R(r)*Y(theta)]. r values lie range [0, 4] with 0.01 step corresponding 400 points. What should be theta step at range [0, 360]?

To get a polar density, How to design .dat file?

Comment: Can you maybe please show an example graph how you want the plot to look like? Then we can maybe tell what the ideal data format for gnuplot should be. Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18792461/7295599 ? The answers might be partly outdated because they were for older gnuplot versions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755331/gnuplot-graphing-and-defining-variables-in-polar-coordinates

Comment: I have numerical radial function with 400 nodes. I will construct angular funtion numerically. How to design .dat file?